# String appears to be valid JSON, but `json_decode()` returns NULL

Tags: php, json

I think I've found where the error lies:

```
    $convertJSON = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=" . $currencyValue . $currencySelectValue . "%3D%3FUSD", true);
    var_dump($convertJSON);
    $convertArr = json_decode($convertJSON, true);
    var_dump($convertArr);
```

I do that to debug, and I get this result (I entered 555 and Euros):

```
string(68) "{lhs: "555 Euros",rhs: "796.64700 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}"
NULL
```

So it seems that the PHP function to decode the JSON object is doing something wrong somewhere. Any help?

Comment: What is `$tickerJSON`? Do you mean `$convertJSON`?

Comment: You may be on to something...

Comment: Still getting a 0 result every time.

Comment: If you enabled `E_NOTICE` and displayed them during the screen while debugging, PHP would warn you. Also, see @yes123's answer regarding the regexp. You need to debug step-by-step to see where it goes wrong... not just wonder why the final answer is wrong.

Comment: It seems I'm getting a NULL when I try to var_dump the json-decoded array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response Google is giving you isn't valid JSON because the labels are not quoted. You'll have to parse it yourself.

```
$response = '{lhs: "555 Euros",rhs: "796.64700 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true';
preg_match('/rhs:\s*"([^"]+)"/', $response, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Output:

```
796.64700 U.S. dollars
```

Answer (score 30):

Not a direct response to this question, but an issue I spent a few hours trying to resolve.

**If you are attempting to decode JSON that came from a remote file via CURL, and if that file is in UTF-8 format**, the beginning of the file may have the following characters (which breaks json_decode():

```
&iuml;&raquo;&iquest;
```

Which you will not see with the naked eye, only via `htmlentities();`  I have no idea why they are there, I traced this all the way to `curl_exec()`, thinking that maybe they were being added there.  In any case, those little bastards were being added only when file is in UTF-8 format.

So, assuming you have no control over the encoding of the source file, you can do something like this before passing the string into json_decode():

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($json);

if($encoding == 'UTF-8') {
  $json = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $json);    
}    

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

I hope I save somebody some time, it took me a few hours of tracing to figure out that's what was happening.

Comment: Oh god, I thought I was going insane! I printed out the response string, and it's a valid JSON, I paste it directly in my PHP code, it converts it to an object perfectly. I store it in a variable - I get an empty string. Those little encoding characters aren't even detectable with subtstr() method. Thank you, Andy!

Comment: Yeah pretty sure you saved me like five hours. Mad ups

Comment: Crazy, I just had the same problem! I even stored the result in a file and it was not parseable. But no editor displayed any suspicious characters... Your trick saved the day.

Comment: Just saved me from going insane! My JSON worked yesterday, I get in today and nothing worked! But now it's fine so **thanks!**

Edit: I should point out though, my json encoding was showing as `ASCII` but this `preg_replace` still fixed it!

Comment: Good one! When testing the json string with `htmlentities()` showed up that a `<html>`tag was outputted before the json. Thx Stackoverflow

Comment: My problem was CURL but solution was different. When I'd removed this line it worked! curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));

Comment: I also had the same kind of problem, but the way I got it solved is by adding `stripslashes($data)` to the code. Lost a few hours, because JSON.stringify() was adding extra quotes when stringifying an array and I needed to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

> strip it of everything but decimal points, commas, and numbers, and give me a result.

Actually you do the exact contrary with your regex. Add a `^` after `[`: `[^` to negate it

```
$currencyValue = preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,]+)/', '', $currencyValue);
```

Comment: I mean stripping something like "16.9 Rubles" so it says "16.9". Is that what you mean too?

Answer (score 1):

to make json_encode workable, you have to add double quote to the result string in order to make it in JSON format.

I tries the simple code below , and it works fine:

```
$data = '{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "7.80177256 Hong Kong dollars",error: "",icc: true}';
$data = str_replace('lhs','"lhs"',$data);
$data = str_replace('rhs','"rhs"',$data);
$data = str_replace('error','"error"',$data);
$data = str_replace('icc','"icc"',$data);
print_r(json_decode($data));
```

## Result:

```
stdClass Object ( [lhs] => 1 U.S. dollar [rhs] => 7.80177256 Hong Kong dollars [error] => [icc] => 1 )
```

Now it is in json_decode object!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Matthews answer:

In case for some reason you want all data; (probably not but just in case?)

```
$c='{lhs: "1 British pound",rhs: "1.5358 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}';
$j=json_decode(preg_replace('/({|,)([a-z]+): /','$1"$2": ',$c));
var_dump($j->{'rhs'});
```

I stumbled across this page before I worked it out so maybe others will too :)