# what is the best method to get the response of a url in php

Tags: php, url

Say I want to get the response of this url:

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD%3D%3FEUR

which is:

{lhs: "100 U.S. dollars",rhs: "79.3839803 Euros",error: "",icc: true}

And then retrieve the rhs value.

How can i achieve this easily in PHP?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336174/string-appears-to-be-valid-json-but-json-decode-returns-null). Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD%3D%3FEUR');
// {lhs: "100 U.S. dollars",rhs: "79.3839803 Euros",error: "",icc: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not returning valid JSON, so the easy way is to fix the string (to make it legal JSON) and decode it.

Something like:

```
<?php
    $output = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD%3D%3FEUR');
    $output = str_replace('rhs','"rhs"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('lhs','"lhs"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('error','"error"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('icc','"icc"',$output);

    $json = json_decode($output);
    $rhs = $json->rhs;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $resp=file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100USD%3D%3FEUR');
    $pos=strpos($resp,'rhs:')+6;
    $pos2=strpos($resp,'"',$pos);
    $euros=substr($resp,$pos,$pos2-$pos);
?>
```