# JSON Syntax Error when using escaped slashes

Tags: php, json

**TOTALLY RE-EDITED QUESTION**

```
<?php
   $s1 = '{"req":"auth","token":"1234567\/\\"}'; // this seems to be valid, isn't it?
   $s2 = '{"req":"auth","token":"123456\/\\7"}'; // this seems to be valid, isn't it?
   $s3 = '{"req":"auth","token":"123456789"}';

   print_r(json_decode($s1,true));
   echo " - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#1 IS:" . json_last_error() . '<br />';

   print_r(json_decode($s2,true));
   echo " - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#2 IS:" . json_last_error() . '<br />';

   print_r(json_decode($s3,true));
   echo " - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#3 IS:" . json_last_error() . '<br />';
?>
```

RESULTS:

```
 - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#1 IS:4
 - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#2 IS:4
Array ( [req] => auth [token] => 123456789 ) - ERRORCODE FOR CASE#3 IS:0
```

QUESTION:

Why `s1` and `s2` do not work, and how to fix this?

Comment: The problem likely has something to do with how you are getting the JSON into PHP, which isn't part of the code you've shared.

Comment: Edited to clear your doubts.

Comment: please share your codebase for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336174/string-appears-to-be-valid-json-but-json-decode-returns-null or, at least, this answer to that question may answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7742778/3449107

Comment: @FlashThunder — You still haven't shown us how the JSON gets into the $str variable.

Comment: Totally re-edited question to fit everybody needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you're testing stuff here, therefore having:

```
$test_json = '{"req":"auth","token":"1234567\/\\"}';
```

While single quotes do ignore things like `\n`, `\\` is still treated as a single backslash. This means your resulting JSON is:

```
{"red":"auth","token":"1234567\/\"}
```

Which, needless to say, is a syntax error.

If you're getting your JSON from an outside source, you won't need to worry about this, but if you're testing with a hardcoded JSON string, you'll need:

```
$test_json = '{"req":"auth","token":"1234567\/\\\\"}';
```

Comment: Please check my edit, seems that it is not the case.

Comment: @FlashThunder... My answer very exactly describes what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call stripslashes function before the json_decode, i.e. add below 2 lines before your first print_r so that it decodes and prints correct array.

```
$s1 = stripslashes($s1);
$s2 = stripslashes($s2);
```